# Single HTML / JS (jQuery) app loaded from file:// URL in FF can make network calls, and receive responses, but response body is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a simple app that I'm writing in a single web page, that is only ever going to live on a network share. It is meant to grab data from a webservice and present it nicely. I'm deving it on my local PC in Firefox 26.0. I'm using jQuery to help with this. The data coming back is XML (from jira, fwiw).

The calls are being made, and the response is being received by the server. The FF web dev tool tells me the response is a 200 OK. However, the response body is empty. The error callback gets called every time.

The code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myjiraserver?lalalalala",
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    processData : false,
    success: function(response) {
        var result = "";
        $(response).find("item type").map( function() {
            if (this.text == "Risk") {
                result += "<p>" + this.text + "</p>";
            }
        } );
        $("#test").html(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Error:  status = ' + xhr.responseText + " " + error + " " + status );
    }
});
```

I run the same code in IE8 and it gets the response, which jQuery successfully parses. (I'd dev it in IE8 but I need the dev tools that FF has; and chrome doesn't work on this PC - another story)

Given I know the webservice is working, and the js works in IE, my working theory is that this is some sort of cross domain issue, but I really have no idea!

Any idea as to what the issue might be? Suggestions for how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it's working in IE is because JQuery uses activex rather than XmlHttpRequest in ie for ajax requests. Standard XHR requests don't allow for local files to access remote servers (or vice versa).

Even if your code ran from a web server, this wouldn't work in firefox or chrome.  I see you're using the 'crossDomain' parameter, but you've misinterpreted it.  From the jquery docs:

> crossDomain (default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests)
>   Type: Boolean
>   If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value  of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain.  (version added: 1.5)

So you set crossDomain to true if you're using jsonp, but you're using a local server-side redirect to the cross-domain resource.

Normally to access a cross-domain api via javascript, you would either use JSONP, or you would use CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), unfortunately neither of which is supported by jira. ([This article](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/182859/recommended-way-to-connect-to-jira-rest-service-from-javascript) states Jira has effectively killed javascript API access).  A third option is, you could set up a middle-man server which fetches the data and returns it to your local page. That middle-man page would have to have CORS enabled.  Here's an example of how to enable CORS headers in PHP: [CORS with php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)

Your javascript would then have to refer to your middleman page and pass it the api page you want to access:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://middeman.com?page="+escape( 'http://myjiraserver?lalalalala' )+"&method=GET"
...
);
```